# Java program not working using the command line

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Short story :
When I run my java application through the Intellij it's all working.

When I run it through the command line I have some issues.

Long story:
First, I have to say that I have a 'lib' folder inside my project with all the Jars I need and I added it as a Library to the project.

When I compile it from the command line I have to specify a '-cp' to the lib folder, otherwise it doesn't load the jars. Even though it looks good, when I run my java application, I get a `'Error: Could not find or load main class awsUpdater'` error

My commands :
For compiling -

```
javac -cp "../../../../lib/*" awsUpdater.java
```

For executing -

```
java -cp "../../../../lib/*" awsUpdater
```

Here's my class (besides the methods)

```
    package AWSUpdater;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class awsUpdater {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String bucketName = "bucket";
        String key        = "ket";

    //AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
    AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance());

    System.out.println("Downloading an object");
    S3Object s3object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(
            bucketName, key));

    //Get new version of android
    String newAndroidVersion = getNewAndroidVersion();

    //Download current versions.json
    String currentJson = displayTextInputStream(s3object.getObjectContent());

    //Edit versions.json with new android version
    String editedJson = editJsonWithCurrentAndroidVersion(currentJson, newAndroidVersion);

    //String editedJson = editJsonDummyCheck(currentJson);

    //Create new file to upload to S3
    createFileWithNewJson(editedJson);

    //Upload new file to S3
    updateVersion(bucketName, key, "versions.json");

}
```

Would appreciate any help with how to compile and execute my program through the command line. thanks !

Comment: is there a main method in that class? is that class in a package? you'll need to provide more info

Comment: so many possibilities of reasons for failure ...

Comment: Added my code besides the methods which is not important @Stultuske

Comment: java -cp "../../../../lib/*" awsUpdater ... How is that supposed to get into the package AWSUpdater ?

Comment: I read that this is how I tell the command line where the lib of jars is. please correct me if i'm wrong. BTW, if run 'java awsUpdater' - same results

Comment: The class name is `AWSUpdater.awsUpdater`. That's what you must pass to `java`. In addition to the jar files, the root directory containing your class files must also be in the classpath, otherwise java can't possibly find them. You should also learn and respect the Java naming conventions. Packages are all lowercase. Classes start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you for the detailed answer, would you mind help me with the command itself? I succeded doing what you said but I still face some issues

Answer (score 1):

you need to add package name

```
java -cp "../../../../lib/*" AWSUpdater.awsUpdater
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but it doesnt work. I compile fine like that :  javac -cp "../../../lib/*" AWSUpdater/awsUpdater.java .   But I'm unable to execute as you stated

Comment: ok so you used this command `javac -cp "../../../lib/*" AWSUpdater/awsUpdater.java` after that type **cd../** and than run this `java -cp "../../../../lib/*" AWSUpdater.awsUpdater`

Comment: The compiling works, the executing doesnt, I get the following error `Error: Could not find or load main class AWSUpdater.awsUpdater
`

Comment: can you please add what is your directory structure and from which directory you are running the command

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the class `awsUpdater` is under the package `AWSUpdater`, so you can not use `java -cp "../../../../lib/*" awsUpdater` directly.
For Example:
I create a project like this:

```
|-test
  |-AWSUpdater
    |-awsUpdater.java
```

Detail of the `awsUpdater.java`:

```
public class awsUpdater {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

then(now I'm in `test/AWSUpdater`):

```
javac awsUpdater.java
java awsUpdater
```

***Everything goes well!***

If I add the class to the package, like this:

```
package AWSUpdater;

public class awsUpdater {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

then(now I'm in `test/AWSUpdater`):

```
javac awsUpdater.java
java awsUpdater
```

here, it will got the error which is same with yours.

Now, you can go to the package's root dir. (here is `test`), and then:

```
javac AWSUpdater/awsUpdater.java
java AWSUpdater/awsUpdater
```

***Now, you will get the correct result.***

Comment: you can try `java -cp "../../../../lib/*" AWSUpdater/awsUpdater`